# FCM add Instance Id to topics after removing from batch remove

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I am subscribing to events from FCM Android client and removing from server side code when something happens in the backend database. So based on this I have ome around a situation where if i subscribe to event `event123` and than based on some factors from **InstanceId API** I call `batchRemove` call from my node backend to remove that person to stop receiving pushes about that id. Then I again client can re-join the event from Android device. But this does not work.

I also tried to call the API from the REST client but I am unable to add the person to that event group. I get 200 OK, but still I am unable to join the group. When I query the instance id, It doesn't give me the event I tried to re-subscribe.

What's the issue? Am I missing something? Or no instance id can rejoin a topic?

**UPDATE**: I have contacted the firebase support for this and this is a bug at the moment. I am not sure if it has been released or not, as I have not been updated with the release status.

Comment: Could it be that there is a delay in getting re-subscribed to the topic? Have you tried checking after a day or so?

Comment: As I already mentioned. It was the bug on the firebase side. Not sure it is fixed or not.